# What is a "SparesMissing event" of a md RAID 5 array?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, mdadm

I have set up a Ubuntu Server 22.04 installation with a xfs filesystem on a RAID 5 /dev/md0 array. Now I get e-mail notifications from the mdadm monitoring, that a "SparesMissing" event has been detected on md device /dev/md0. What is a "SparesMissing" event? Is there an error in the filesystem or raid 5 array? Do I have to do something to prevent data loss?

Answer (score 0):

In your mdadm configuration you have stated that there are spares and there are less found than mdadm is told there would be.

See `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` and change `spares=n` it to the actual spares you will be using and the message will disappear. Unless the intention is to work with that amount of spare disks. In that case your disk setup is physically missing a spare disk.